# Etymology of the words ''Wave''

Tags: etymology, proto-indo-european, germanic-languages, slavic-languages

Do the words Wave(English) Welle(German) Vague(French) have the same Etymology as Val(Serbo-Croatian,Slovenian),Vlna(Czech,Slovakian),BолнаVolna.

All these words mean the same thing-Wave. but I found it surprising, given their relative similarity, that they have a different Proto-Indo-European root.

Wave/Welle comes from the Inde-European [*wegh](https://www.etymonline.com/word/*wegh-?ref=etymonline_crossreference) where Val/Vlna comes from [*wel](https://www.etymonline.com/word/*wel-)

Can anyone explain why these word that mean the same thing and are so alike still do not have the same etymology?

Answer (score 5):

First note that German *Welle* and English *wave* aren't cognates. Grimm derive German *Welle* from a verb *[walen](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GW04638#XGW04638)* "to writhe, to wallow, to roll" that is traced to Indogermanic *vel (in their notation, identical to your *wel). There is another German word for "wave", *[Woge](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GW24689#XGW24689)* (< *wage*) that derives from Indogermanic  *wegh and that is related to English wave. French *vague* is probably a loan from Germanic.

I don't know details about the etymology of *val* and *vlna*. Are they inherited from proto-Slavic or are they loan words from German?

Comment: The Slavic words are cognate with, not borrowed from, German Welle. French vague is not borrowed from (High) German, but from Old Norse, via the Vikings.

Answer (score 3):

These sorts of coincidences happen quite often in comparative linguistics, just by random chance. For a famous example, German *haben* (~English "have") and Latin *habēre* mean the same thing, but come from totally separate roots; *haben* is instead cognate with Latin *capere* "seize", via Grimm's Law.

The main similarity between all these words is the initial /v/, which goes back to PIE. It might be a coincidence that **wegh* and **wel* started with the same phoneme, or it might not (if one affected the other), but all the later similarities can be traced back to this.

Comment: *haben* and *habere* are from separate roots, but is it really random chance that their uses correspond so closely?  That would imply an experiment with no contact.

Comment: Draw the dividing line between way, valley, weave, vague, weigh -- is the wiggle a coincidence?